# paramiko connect is not working because of BadHostKeyException exception

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to ssh server using python paramiko module, But I am getting BadHostKeyException exception while connecting. Can anybody redirect me, how to solve this exception.

```
import paramiko

def checkSSH(host,user,password,command):
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password)
    print ssh.exec_command(command)
    ssh.close()
    return ssh

username='fakeuser'
password='fakepasswd'
ips =  ['2.2.2.2']
response={}
ssh_issue=0
for ip in ips:
        try:
                print ip
                checkSSH(ip,username,password,'date')
        except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as e:
                print str(e)
                #I Need to do something here to get rid of this execption and retry
        except:
                import traceback
                print traceback.format_exc()
                response[ip]='SSH_Needs_Reloading'
                ssh_issue=1
```

Comment: yes, I am using ubuntu.

Comment: @user87005 Can ssh to the machine successfully by hand ?

Comment: yes, it is working fine. after adding the key manually.

(man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
25:b7:82:87:78:98:b2:dc:26:72:17:54:a7:78:cb:fb.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R x.x.x.x
RSA host key for x.x.x.x has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: What is `e.key` and `e.expected_key`?